# Wrapping Resilience4j circuitbreaker around a service method with multiple arguments

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

Resilience4j-circuitbreaker allows us to wrap a service using decorator functions, but from what I can tell it only allows functional interfaces such as Supplier, Consumer, and Function which accept at most 1 input.

If I have a service which has a method which accepts 2 arguments, how would i be able to wrap it with the circuitbreaker?

In https://www.baeldung.com/resilience4j:

```
interface RemoteService {
    int process(int i);
}

CircuitBreakerRegistry registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(config);
CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = registry.circuitBreaker("my");
Function<Integer, Integer> decorated = CircuitBreaker
  .decorateFunction(circuitBreaker, service::process);
```

If process(int i) was something like process(int i, String s), which decorator Function would be able to be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CircuitBreaker.decorateCallable`:

```
CircuitBreaker.decorateCallable(circuitBreaker, () -> service.process(i, s))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?
I have a service that has two input arguments and return void.

Comment: `CircuitBreaker.decorateRunnable(circuitBreaker, () -> yourMethcodCall(arg1, arg2));`

Comment: Any idea how to use fallbacks with this? @AlexanderPankin